# Webpack config meaning&function of key-value(array) in the entry object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Here's part of entry object in one webpack config file i met

```
...
  entry: {
    'lib.min': ['react', 'react-dom']},
    ...
  }
...
```

From this webpack.config.js file on github:
https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui/blob/develop/webpack.config.js#L99

I'm confusing how webpack deal with this line. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You are just simply saying:

"Ok webpack, i want you to put `react` and `react-dom` into the same file and call it `lib.min`, then consider it an entry point too".

Basic it!